# Pull random string from array and insert in sentence

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, getelementbyid

How do I pull a string randomly from an array, and insert that string into a span?
Heres the arrays:

```
var startupX = ['Uber', 'Google', 'Amazon', 'Apple', 'Facebook', 'Twitter'];
var startupY = ['Slack', 'Trello', 'Tesla', 'Hyperloop', 'Harvest'];
```

And these are the spans that a startup name needs to go into

```
<h1 id="xForY"></h1>
  <h1>A startup that is 
    <span id="startupX"></span>, but for 
    <span id="startupY"></span>
    </h1>
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Is it just the random part, or do you not know how to insert *any* text into a span using JS?

Comment: You can get your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find a random element from each of the arrays. [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) will help you with that.

Then you can use the DOM API to insert it into your page:

```js
var startupX = ['Uber', 'Google', 'Amazon', 'Apple', 'Facebook', 'Twitter'];
var startupY = ['Slack', 'Trello', 'Tesla', 'Hyperloop', 'Harvest'];

var x = startupX[Math.floor(Math.random()*startupX.length)];
var y = startupY[Math.floor(Math.random()*startupY.length)];

document.getElementById('startupX').innerHTML = x;
document.getElementById('startupY').innerHTML = y;
```

```html
<h1 id="xForY"></h1>
<h1>A startup that is 
    <span id="startupX"></span>, but for 
    <span id="startupY"></span>
</h1>
```

Comment: This is great, to try and understand how it works tho-- innerHTML = x is taking the result of var x and replacing "startupX"?

Comment: @OwenSchifferli It sets the *inner HTML* of the element  with id `startupX` to the content of variable `x`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) will give you a number from 0 inclusive to 1 exclusive `[0, 1)`.

You can use that to get a random number that is within the max array index:

```
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * startupX.length);
```

Then you can use this index to access your array:

```
startupX[randomIndex];
```

Having the value you can place it on the element:

```
document.getElementById('startupX').innerHTML = startupX[randomIndex];
```